# 書類などを運営に送信して承認されたらシステムが使えるようになる仕組み

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, django

現在Laravel8で、fxサービスや株取引、Uber eatsの配達員用アプリなどで用いられてるような、身分証明書などの書類を運営に送り、承認された人のみサービスを利用できるアプリを作ろうと思っています。
大体の仕組みは想像できるのですが、この様な仕組みの物は具体的な固有名詞などはあるのでしょうか？
自分なりに色々調べてはいるのですがサンプルなどが全く見つかりません。どなたかご教示願います。

Answer (score 0):

KYC; Know Your Customer ([Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/KYC)) かと思います。
オンラインで完結させる場合は特に eKYC と呼ばれます。

検索してみると、 [LINE](https://clova.line.me/line-ekyc/) や [docomo](https://www.docomo.ne.jp/biz/service/kyc/) などがサービス提供しているのが見つかります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
初めて固有名詞がわかりました！

KYCを自分で実装するのって結構難しいですかね？
私が作ろうとしているのが結構マイナーな公的書類？でして、それを送信してもらった後に権限を付与したいんですよね。